# How to make a worker function interact with another worker function?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to get 5 threads that wait at a function funB through pthread_cond_wait, until 5 threads from function funA signal them all through pthread_cond_signal, but the output doesn't come out how I wanted. This is my code:

I compiled it through `gcc -o mini2 mini2.c -lpthread` and ran it through `./mini2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t alock;
pthread_cond_t acond;
pthread_mutex_t block;
pthread_cond_t bcond;

void* funA(void *atid) {
    printf("funA %p: A got in\n",&atid);

    printf("funA %p: I want to signal\n",&atid);

    pthread_cond_signal(&bcond);
}

void* funB(void *btid) {
    printf("funB %p: B got in\n",&btid);

    pthread_cond_wait(&bcond,&block);

    printf("funB %p: I got signalled\n",&btid);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    pthread_t a[5];
    pthread_t b[5];

    pthread_mutex_init(&alock,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&acond,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&block,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&bcond,NULL);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&a[i],NULL,funA,&a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&b[i],NULL,funB,&b[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_join(a[i],NULL);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_join(b[i],NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&alock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&acond);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&block);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&bcond);

}
```

The output came out as and I had to terminate it through Ctrl + C:

```
funA 0x7fd870810ee8: A got in
funA 0x7fd870810ee8: I want to signal
funA 0x7fd87000fee8: A got in
funA 0x7fd87000fee8: I want to signal
funB 0x7fd86e00bee8: B got in
funB 0x7fd86d80aee8: B got in
funB 0x7fd86d009ee8: B got in
funA 0x7fd86f00dee8: A got in
funA 0x7fd86f00dee8: I want to signal
funA 0x7fd86e80cee8: A got in
funA 0x7fd86e80cee8: I want to signal
funB 0x7fd86c808ee8: B got in
funA 0x7fd86f80eee8: A got in
funA 0x7fd86f80eee8: I want to signal
funB 0x7fd867ffeee8: B got in
funB 0x7fd86e00bee8: I got signalled
funB 0x7fd86d009ee8: I got signalled
^C
```

From this output, I believe I was able to understand that it was just funA's threads signalling too early, since there were no threads at funB at `pthread_cond_wait(&bcond,&block)` when the more recent funA pthreads were calling `pthread_cond_signal(&bcond)`, so I tried a different way by adding a bwaiting int variable, which makes the funA threads wait until there are funB threads to signal. However, the output doesn't come how I wanted. The output I wanted was for `printf("funB %p: I got signalled\n",&btid)` to be printed 5 times to show that all threads made it through `pthread_cond_wait(&bcond,&block)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t alock;
pthread_cond_t acond;
pthread_mutex_t block;
pthread_cond_t bcond;

int bwaiting = 0;

void* funA(void *atid) {
    printf("funA %p: A got in\n",&atid);

    printf("funA %p: I want to signal\n",&atid);
    if(bwaiting == 0) {
        printf("funA %p: I can't signal yet since no one at B is waiting. I'm waiting...\n",&atid);
        pthread_cond_wait(&acond,&alock);
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&bcond);
}

void* funB(void *btid) {
    printf("funB %p: B got in\n",&btid);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&block);
    bwaiting++;
    if(bwaiting > 0) {
        printf("funB %p: I'm waiting at B now. I need to let A know I'm waiting\n",&btid);
        pthread_cond_signal(&acond);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&block);
    pthread_cond_wait(&bcond,&block);

    printf("funB %p: I got signalled\n",&btid);
    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    pthread_t a[5];
    pthread_t b[5];

    pthread_mutex_init(&alock,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&acond,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&block,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&bcond,NULL);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&a[i],NULL,funA,&a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&b[i],NULL,funB,&b[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_join(a[i],NULL);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pthread_join(b[i],NULL);
    }

}
```

This is the output using the same compiling and running method as the previous code:

```
funA 0x7ff0691d0ee8: A got in
funA 0x7ff0691d0ee8: I want to signal
funA 0x7ff0691d0ee8: I can't signal yet since no one at B is waiting. I'm waiting...
funA 0x7ff0689cfee8: A got in
funA 0x7ff0689cfee8: I want to signal
funA 0x7ff0689cfee8: I can't signal yet since no one at B is waiting. I'm waiting...
funA 0x7ff0679cdee8: A got in
funA 0x7ff0679cdee8: I want to signal
funA 0x7ff0679cdee8: I can't signal yet since no one at B is waiting. I'm waiting...
funA 0x7ff0671ccee8: A got in
funA 0x7ff0671ccee8: I want to signal
funA 0x7ff0671ccee8: I can't signal yet since no one at B is waiting. I'm waiting...
funB 0x7ff0661caee8: B got in
funB 0x7ff0669cbee8: B got in
funB 0x7ff0669cbee8: I'm waiting at B now. I need to let A know I'm waiting
funA 0x7ff0681ceee8: A got in
funB 0x7ff0661caee8: I'm waiting at B now. I need to let A know I'm waiting
funA 0x7ff0681ceee8: I want to signal
funB 0x7ff0669cbee8: I got signalled
funB 0x7ff0649c7ee8: B got in
funB 0x7ff0659c9ee8: B got in
funB 0x7ff0651c8ee8: B got in
^C
```

How will I be able to get all funB threads through `pthread_cond_wait(&bcond,&block)`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Condition variable usage and semantics

The correct semantics for CV use is that a thread uses a CV, when necessary, to wait for a condition to be satisfied.  Thus, the correct idiom always involves checking before waiting to determine whether to a wait is needed at all.

Additionally, even when a thread is confident that the CV would not have been signaled unless conditions were right for that thread to proceed, it usually cannot be confident that the condition is ***still*** satisfied when it actually reacquires the mutex and returns from the CV wait.  Therefore, the correct idiom always involves checking the condition *again* after waking up, and being prepared to resume waiting.  This condition recheck also catches spurious wakeups, which can happen with many flavors of CVs, including pthreads's.

The idiom for a CV wait therefore looks like this:

1. Acquire the mutex
2. Check whether the condition to proceed is satisfied

   - if so, then skip ahead to step (5)
   - otherwise, ...
3. Wait on the CV
4. Upon waking, loop back to step (2)
5. Do anything that requires protection of the mutex
6. Release the mutex

### Condition variables in your program

So a key question to ask is what your threads are waiting *for*.  From your description and first code, that seems to be roughly "at least one more thread has passed through `funA` than so far has passed through `funB`".

In that case, your second attempt moves in the correct direction, but it has the idiom backwards.  Instead of delaying threads' signaling from `funA()`, you should capture some record that they have done so, that threads in `funB()` can check (and re-check).  That could be a simple counter, like you're already using, but incremented in `funA()` instead of in `funB()`, and *decremented in `funB()`* so that each thread passing through `funA()` allows only one thread to pass `funB()`.

**Other important considerations:**

- Any thread that wants to access the counter, read or write, must hold the mutex while doing so.
- Any thread that wants to wait on the CV must hold the mutex locked when it enters the wait.  The codes presented in the question consistently fail to do that.

### Addendum

I presume that you are using CVs because the exercise requires you to do so.  If not, then a counting semaphore would provide a much simpler solution to this particular problem.

Comment: I see. What should my code be instead? I put `bwaiting--` before `if(bwaiting > 0)` in `funB` and `bwaiting++` before `if(bwaiting == 0)` in `funA`. Where should my counters be?

Comment: @amy37195, I strongly recommend choosing a variable name that reflects its purpose, and again, it is not how many threads are waiting that you want to count.  So something like `canProceed`, which is incremented in `funA()`, under protection of the mutex, before the CV is signaled, and which is decremented in `funB()`, under protection of the mutex, after return from the wait  *and* verifying that it is greater than 0.

Comment: Also, to be clear: I see no reason for a CV wait in `funA()`.